# MongoDB Query Error : '$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating a mongoDB query that will be executed in Jaspersoft Studio,

Currently I am having error which I think the query is finding ObjectID format of "ctr" field.

**Error Message:**

```
 '$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1'
```

The dataset that the query is looking

```
{
    ordernumbers: 1001,
    items: "testitems",
    orderlogss:
        [
            {
                "ctr": {"$oid": "6106d15ca48148060dbbec69"},
                "stat": "Ordered",
                "time": {"$date": 1627836764264}
            },
            {
                "ctr": {"$oid": "6106d15ca48148060dbbec68"},
                "stat": "Ordered",
                "time": {"$date": 1627836764265}
            },
            {
                "ctr": {"$oid": "6106db35abcea00b8d901035"},
                "stat": "Registered",
                "time": {"$date": 1627839285518}
            },
            {
                "ctr": {"$oid": "6106db893a008e1a0112b8d8"},
                "time": {"$date": 1627839369359}
            },
            {
                "ctr": {"$oid": "6106db8f3a008e1a0112b922"},
                "stat": "Dispensed",
                "time": {"$date": 1627839375597}
            }
        ]
}
```

I think the error is caused by automatic conversion of ObjectID to String. How can I make it to Object ID format and also the time is not in string format. ex. ctr: ObjectId("6106d15ca48148060dbbec69"), time: ISODate("2025-05-28T18:29:59.999Z")

**This is the query I am using**

```
[
    {
        $project: {
            itemfinal: "$items",
            ordernumberfinal: "$ordernumbers",
            rows: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$orderlogss",
                        in: {
                            "k": "$$this.stat",
                            "v": "$$this.time"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "rows.finalitem": "$itemfinal",
            "rows.finalorder": "$ordernumberfinal"
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$rows"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: please provide your sample output data

Comment: you expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue comes from this nested object:

```
{
 "ctr": {"$oid": "6106db893a008e1a0112b8d8"},
 "time": {"$date": 1627839369359}
}
```

This object is missing the `stat` field and the result is a missing value. that's why `$arrayToObject` fails.

You can just wrap it with [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in your `$map` operation to avoid this, like so:

```
{
  "$ifNull": [
    "$$this.stat",
    "replacement-stat"
  ]
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lVZlVhYBzKx)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! So it is not really the ObjectID format the cause of this problem.  Already applied the $ifNull and it runs as expected. Thank again!